# slides not rendering properly in R 4.0.3

Tags: xaringan

I have upgraded to R 4.0.3 and I am having some rendering issues in xaringan.  Specifically, I am getting the following output:

Version info:
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin17.0
system         x86_64, darwin17.0
status
major          4
minor          0.3
year           2020
month          10
day            10
svn rev        79318
language       R
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="" xml:lang="">
  <head>
    <title>Algorithmic trading and investment</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Barry Quinn" />
    <meta name="date" content="2021-01-14" />
    <link href="libs/remark-css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="libs/panelset/panelset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="libs/panelset/panelset.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/xaringanExtra-webcam/webcam.js"></script>
    <script id="xaringanExtra-webcam-options" type="application/json">{"width":"200","height":"200","margin":"1em"}</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sfah.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="source">




layout: true
  
&lt;div class="my-footer"&gt;&lt;span&gt;quinference.com&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;


```{=html}
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;style type="text/css"&gt;.xaringan-extra-logo {
width: 110px;
height: 128px;
z-index: 0;
background-image: url(img/redlogo.png);
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top:1em;right:1em;
}
&lt;/style&gt;
&lt;script&gt;(function () {
  let tries = 0
  function addLogo () {
    if (typeof slideshow === 'undefined') {
      tries += 1
      if (tries &lt; 10) {
        setTimeout(addLogo, 100)
      }
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll('.remark-slide-content:not(.title-slide):not(.inverse):not(.hide_logo)')
        .forEach(function (slide) {
          const logo = document.createElement('div')
          logo.classList = 'xaringan-extra-logo'
          logo.href = null
          slide.appendChild(logo)
        })
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addLogo)
})()&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```



---
name: ATL-title
class: inverse,left, middle
background-image: url(img/markus-spiske-466ENaLuhLY-unsplash.png)
background-size: cover

# Algorithmic Trading and Investing (FIN7030)


# .fancy[Lecture 2: High performance cloud computing in finance]

.large[Barry Quinn PhD CStat | Queen's Management School | 2021-01-14]

&lt;!-- this ends up being the title slide since seal = FALSE--&gt;

---
class:inverse
# Outline 

- .salt[What is cloud computing?]
- .fat[Your Turn: Introduction to the QMS_HPCC]
- .salt[Taxonomy of parallel computing]
- .fat[Performance computing in Python]
- .salt[Financial applications in the cloud]
- .salt[Economics of the cloud computing]
- .salt[Some case studies]
---
    </textarea>
<style data-target="print-only">@media screen {.remark-slide-container{display:block;}.remark-slide-scaler{box-shadow:none;}}</style>
<script src="https://remarkjs.com/downloads/remark-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script>var slideshow = remark.create({
"highlightStyle": "github",
"highlightLines": true,
"countIncrementalSlides": true,
"ratio": "16:9"
});
if (window.HTMLWidgets) slideshow.on('afterShowSlide', function (slide) {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
});
(function(d) {
  var s = d.createElement("style"), r = d.querySelector(".remark-slide-scaler");
  if (!r) return;
  s.type = "text/css"; s.innerHTML = "@page {size: " + r.style.width + " " + r.style.height +"; }";
  d.head.appendChild(s);
})(document);

(function(d) {
  var el = d.getElementsByClassName("remark-slides-area");
  if (!el) return;
  var slide, slides = slideshow.getSlides(), els = el[0].children;
  for (var i = 1; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slide = slides[i];
    if (slide.properties.continued === "true" || slide.properties.count === "false") {
      els[i - 1].className += ' has-continuation';
    }
  }
  var s = d.createElement("style");
  s.type = "text/css"; s.innerHTML = "@media print { .has-continuation { display: none; } }";
  d.head.appendChild(s);
})(document);
// delete the temporary CSS (for displaying all slides initially) when the user
// starts to view slides
(function() {
  var deleted = false;
  slideshow.on('beforeShowSlide', function(slide) {
    if (deleted) return;
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, node;
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      node = sheets[i].ownerNode;
      if (node.dataset["target"] !== "print-only") continue;
      node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
    deleted = true;
  });
})();
(function() {
  "use strict"
  // Replace <script> tags in slides area to make them executable
  var scripts = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.remark-slides-area .remark-slide-container script'
  );
  if (!scripts.length) return;
  for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    var code = document.createTextNode(scripts[i].textContent);
    s.appendChild(code);
    var scriptAttrs = scripts[i].attributes;
    for (var j = 0; j < scriptAttrs.length; j++) {
      s.setAttribute(scriptAttrs[j].name, scriptAttrs[j].value);
    }
    scripts[i].parentElement.replaceChild(s, scripts[i]);
  }
})();
(function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (/^(https?:)?\/\//.test(links[i].getAttribute('href'))) {
      links[i].target = '_blank';
    }
  }
})();
(function(time) {
  var d2 = function(number) {
    return ('0' + number).slice(-2); // left-pad 0 to minutes/seconds
  },

  time_format = function(total) {
    var secs = Math.abs(total) / 1000;
    var h = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(secs % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.round(secs % 60);
    var res = d2(m) + ':' + d2(s);
    if (h > 0) res = h + ':' + res;
    return res;  // [hh:]mm:ss
  },

  slide_number_div = function(i) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName('remark-slide-number').item(i);
  },

  current_page_number = function(i) {
    return slide_number_div(i).firstChild.textContent;  // text "i / N"
  };

  var timer = document.createElement('span'); timer.id = 'slide-time-left';
  var time_left = time, k = slideshow.getCurrentSlideIndex(),
      last_page_number = current_page_number(k);

  setInterval(function() {
    time_left = time_left - 1000;
    timer.innerHTML = ' ' + time_format(time_left);
    if (time_left < 0) timer.style.color = 'red';
  }, 1000);

  slide_number_div(k).appendChild(timer);

  slideshow.on('showSlide', function(slide) {
    var i = slide.getSlideIndex(), n = current_page_number(i);
    // reset timer when a new slide is shown and the page number is changed
    if (last_page_number !== n) {
      time_left = time; last_page_number = n;
      timer.innerHTML = ' ' + time_format(time); timer.style.color = null;
    }
    slide_number_div(i).appendChild(timer);
  });
})(120000);
// adds .remark-code-has-line-highlighted class to <pre> parent elements
// of code chunks containing highlighted lines with class .remark-code-line-highlighted
(function(d) {
  const hlines = d.querySelectorAll('.remark-code-line-highlighted');
  const preParents = [];
  const findPreParent = function(line, p = 0) {
    if (p > 1) return null; // traverse up no further than grandparent
    const el = line.parentElement;
    return el.tagName === "PRE" ? el : findPreParent(el, ++p);
  };

  for (let line of hlines) {
    let pre = findPreParent(line);
    if (pre && !preParents.includes(pre)) preParents.push(pre);
  }
  preParents.forEach(p => p.classList.add("remark-code-has-line-highlighted"));
})(document);</script>

<script>
slideshow._releaseMath = function(el) {
  var i, text, code, codes = el.getElementsByTagName('code');
  for (i = 0; i < codes.length;) {
    code = codes[i];
    if (code.parentNode.tagName !== 'PRE' && code.childElementCount === 0) {
      text = code.textContent;
      if (/^\\\((.|\s)+\\\)$/.test(text) || /^\\\[(.|\s)+\\\]$/.test(text) ||
          /^\$\$(.|\s)+\$\$$/.test(text) ||
          /^\\begin\{([^}]+)\}(.|\s)+\\end\{[^}]+\}$/.test(text)) {
        code.outerHTML = code.innerHTML;  // remove <code></code>
        continue;
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
};
slideshow._releaseMath(document);
</script>
<!-- dynamically load mathjax for compatibility with self-contained -->
<script>
(function () {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src  = 'https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML';
  if (location.protocol !== 'file:' && /^https?:/.test(script.src))
    script.src  = script.src.replace(/^https?:/, '');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
````